# Need help installing new ceiling light

Tags: kitchens

There are only two wires coming out of ceiling, both are black and only one reads there is power. I need to install a new ceiling light fixture but don’t know what to do.

Comment: Can you post photos looking up into the ceiling box please?

Answer (score 1):

The one that reads power gets the black (or brown) wire.  The one that does not gets the white wire.

If it's on 24x7 at this point, you accidentally made a mess and it will take more to untangle it.